# Authlogic edit_password_reset_url in Functional / Integration Tests

Tags: authlogic, functional-testing

I am trying to implement some tests to validate the behavior for Authlogic password resets as explained in http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic/

I am using Authlogic, Shoulda, Webrat and Factory Girl and here's my test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest


  setup :activate_authlogic

  context "A registered user" do
    setup do
      @reggie = Factory(:reggie)

    end

    should "not allow logged in users to change password" do
      visit signin_path
      fill_in 'Email', :with => @reggie.email
      fill_in 'Password', :with => @reggie.password
      click_button 'Sign In'
      assert_equal controller.session['user_credentials'], @reggie.persistence_token
      visit change_password_path
      assert_equal account_path, path
      assert_match /must be logged out/, flash[:notice]
      visit signout_path
      assert_equal controller.session['user_credentials'], nil
      visit change_password_path
      assert_equal change_password_path, path
    end

    should "allow logged out users to change password" do
      visit signout_path
      assert_equal controller.session['user_credentials'], nil
      visit change_password_path
      assert_template :new
      fill_in 'email', :with => @reggie.email
      click_button 'Reset my password'
      assert_match /Please check your email/, flash[:notice]
      assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
      sent = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first
      assert_equal [@reggie.email], sent.to
      assert_match /Password Reset Instructions/, sent.subject
      assert_not_nil @reggie.perishable_token
      #TODO
      p "Perishable Token #{@reggie.perishable_token}"
      assert_match assigns[:edit_password_reset_url], sent.body
    end
  end
end
```

In the last 2 lines of the test, I am trying to make sure the link sent out has the right perishable_token and it always comes up different between the printed Perishable Token and the token in the link sent out.

How should I test this behavior?

Thanks, Siva

Answer (score 0):

Careful. Authlogic is magic. Certain operations cause the User object to mutate and when it does, the perishable_token well, perishes (gets regenerated).

I wonder if your visit `signout_path` is really logging you out. Typically, if your UserSession is RESTful you'd have to issue an HTTP DELETE to the resource to actually delete the session. Just visiting the path (with a GET) won't delete the session unless you have an explicit route for it (mapping e.g. `'/logout'` to `:controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'destroy'`)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in `notifier.rb` to this:

```
body          :edit_password_resets_url => edit_password_resets_url(user.perishable_token)
```